# How to edit text in Scribus 1.4.7 document created from template?

Tags: text, template-design, scribus, document-setup, publishing

I spent 4 hours creating a document layout for a resume using Scribus. I'm new to Scribus, but I picked it up pretty easily through tutorials. I created two master pages (one for a first page, and one for all others) and when I was satisfied with the design, I saved it as a template. But, when I do "New From Template" it creates a document, but ***I am unable to edit the new document text***. In fact, text frames are *somewhat* selectable, but not editable.

I can bring up the story editor and I can edit text in the attached master pages. But, ***I cannot edit text in the actual page itself***!

[image: (screenshot)]

[image]

This doesn't seem to be an issue with Story Editor like others have had. The main symptom is that -- even after I've closed the "Edit Master Pages" dialog, and then clicked on a regular page in the outline, "Edit Text" is grayed out in the Edit menu, and there is no way to access that option at all from right-clicking a text frame in my document.

I hope that helps clarify what I am experiencing. I've heard Scribus had some problems, but I've been impressed so far with what it can do. It's just this bug or whatever that is preventing me from going any further and I don't want to recreate everything from scratch. Isn't that what master pages and templates were supposed to help one avoid?

*What am I doing wrong?*

I'm not sure what information is needed to troubleshoot this further, but I can tell you my system:

### My System

- Windows 10 64-bit Home
- Scribus 1.4.7

### Original question in case somebody edits it:

> How to edit text in Scribus 1.4.7 after in new document created from template?

Answer (score 1):

If the text frames are on the Master pages, you will only be able to edit them from the Master layout. These are generally meant for auto. text (e.g. page number) or text that you would like to appear on all pages of your document (you can think of it like headers and footers in Writer/Word).

If you want your text frames to be editable by the template user, you should insert them in the Normal layout and if you want to their position and size to be fixed, the best way to go is to lock both: `Item` > `Is locked` and `Item` > `Size is locked` (shortcuts: `Ctrl+L` & `Ctrl+Shift+L`).

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion! I think you have a better understanding of what the issue is. I know there is a "Convert to Master Page" option in the Page menu ... Can I convert a master page to a regular page?

Comment: No, but you can copy paste the frames from a master page to the actual page... Btw, Norbert and myself are describing the same issue... the frame you have on the master page are not editable on the actual page.

Comment: Welcome! Like a.l.e said, you cannot convert a master page (back) to a normal page but if you copy-paste the required elements from the master, they will be positioned at the exact same spots in the "normal" layout. I like the 2-column layout for your resume :) You can align your paragraphs to "baseline grid" to get them on the same lines from column to column if needed. You may also use a different layer for the elements that you would like to remain fix, and lock the layer altogether. Keep up the good work!

Answer (score 0):

Since you're not providing your template, I can only guess what the reason for your problem could be.

From my understanding, your issue does not relate to the templates but to a misunderstanding about what "master pages" are in Scribus.

You have to consider the items in your "master pages" as a background decoration for your page.

On top of this, you can use master pages to set:

- the page size
- the guides on the page
- the page numbers (which are some sort of decoration)

What you cannot do: edit the frames from the master page, in your actual page.

There are a few ways to create "standard frames" in Scribus but, since I'm not even sure that this is your issue, giving you detailed suggestions about it is not the topic of this question (some hints: have a look at the guides and the scrapbook; feel free to ask further questions about this topic...)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm new to Scribus. I'd be happy to provide my template if you can explain how to upload files to this forum. I've made some discoveries since yesterday. Now I see that I can edit the two master pages all I want, but I can't find a way to edit my actual document (3-pages)! Frustrating a bit.

Comment: You can upload the .sla file to a file sharing service like https://framadrop.org and share in here the link.

Comment: I added some screenshots to illustrate what the problem is and what it is not just now. It looks like @Norbert may have a good understanding of what is going on so I'm going to try his solution first and report back.